# Musicbrainz querying artist and release

Tags: web-services, musicbrainz

I am trying to get an artist and their albums. So reading this page https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/XML_Web_Service/Version_2 i created the following query to get Michael Jackson's albums

```
http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=artist:michael%20jackson?inc=releases+recordings
```

My understanding is to add `?inc=releases+recordings` at the end of the URL which should return Michael Jackson's albums however this doesnt seem to return the correct results or i cant seem to narrow down the results? I then thought to use the `{MBID}` but again thats not returned in the artists query (which is why im trying to use `inc` in my query)

```
http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=artist:michael%20jackson
```

Can anyone suggest where im going wrong with this?

Comment: https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/XML_Web_Service/Version_2#Introduction and https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/XML_Web_Service/Version_2#Lookups both say that what you're doing is a search which is documented at https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/XML_Web_Service/Version_2/Search and doesn't support inc arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not searching for the correct Entity. What you want is to get the discography, not artist's infos. Additionally, query *fields* syntax is not correct (you must use [Lucene Search Syntax](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#package_description)).

Here is what you're looking for:

```
http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release-group/?query=artist:"michael jackson" AND primarytype:"album"
```

We're targeting the `release-group` entity to get the albums, searching for a specific `artist` and filtering the results to limit them to albums. (accepted values are: album, single, ep, other)

There are more options to fit your needs, for example you can filter the type of albums using the `secondarytype` parameter. Here is the query to retrieve only live albums:

```
http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release-group/?query=artist:"michael jackson" AND primarytype:"album" AND secondarytype="live"
```

Here is the doc:
https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/XML_Web_Service/Version_2/Search

Note that to be able to use MB's API you need to understand how it is structured, especially, the relations between release_group, release and medium.

Comment: Thanks for that, just some clarification. How did you know type:1 is for albums? I cant find any reference to see how you knew that? Finally if i wanted to include MJ's date of birth i dont think its possible using 'release-group' so i thought to use 'AND begin' which didnt do the trick does this mean i would have to revert back to 'artist'? Or is there a way to include additional details (sorry but i think im missing something obvious here). Thx

Comment: I don't remember where I found this (I probably discovered that by myself playing with a dump some time ago), but you can directly put "album" if you prefer (looks like schema changed since I last used it, so I edited my answer). Here is the list of types and subtypes available: musicbrainz.org/doc/Release_Group/Type nb. don't forget to accept my answer if that's the query you were looking for. thx!